# Rails Nested N+1 Query Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Associations are like this:

```
vendor has shipments  
shipment has order
order has products
```

In My controller I have written as

```
@shipments = @vendor.shipments.includes(:order)
```

But in my view I am using like

```
shipment.order.products.collect(&:name)
```

So it is returning N+1 Query issue by Rails 'bullet' gem

Anyone Help me to resolve this problem of Nested N+1 Query Issue? 
How I need to write in the controller?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@shipments = @vendor.shipments.includes(:order => :products)
```

should work. Read more about it here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#nested-associations-hash

Comment: Thanks a lot Nash..It is working. Earlier I have tried @vendor.shipments.includes(:order => (:includes => :products)), etc.. thanks once again for sharing the link.